# How do you create and save .py file from the py console

Tags: ironpython

Is there a built-in way to do this, or do i have to revert to using System.IO ?

ie:  I want to define and save this class while using the IronPython console.

```
class Hello:
   print "Hello StackOverflow viewer"
```

Is there a built-in way in IronPython to save this class to disk for future use?

Thanks a lot.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you need to select the text, copy and paste it into something you can save.

Answer (score -1):

can't idle save py files? honestly I can't remember :) -edit- oops, I just saw you're trying to use IronPython, sorry my bad